# Remove everything except match of regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions, copy-paste

I have a file with a structure like:

```
some text and numbers and a final number: 1.213,31
some other number 1231 and text 

again some text and a final number: 53,00
something else
again a final number: 1.233,54
```

Now I want to create a file looking like:

```
1.213,31
53,00
1.233,54
```

I can use `higlight-regexp` and the regexp `[0-9,.]+$` to match the correct content, but I don't know how to remove the rest of the file or alternatively copy everything higlighted by this regexp into another buffer.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `query-replace-regexp` with `.*?\([0-9\,\.]+\)$ → \1`. And then `keep-lines` with the same regexp.

Answer (score 1):

> alternatively copy everything [matching] this regexp into another buffer.

You can do that with `occur`

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> `: \([0-9,.]+\)$` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\1` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Or, if less-specific is fine, just:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> `[0-9,.]+$` <kbd>RET</kbd>